What is the average performance benchmark on AWS Step Functions?
We adopted AWS Step Functions a couple of months ago. We expect a lot of payload to run through each (~1M records) in the near future and we're busy testing performance. The results on almost a blank state machine is pretty bad from what expected.
EXAMPLE
// Payload

{
        "uuid": "2f20e60e-494d-4597-9760-2e103b1a6379",
        "amount": 17554,
        "accountNumber": "1111111",
        "bank": "TYME",
        "branchCode": "979592",
        "type": "RTC",
        "date": "2024-01-08T15:10:37.979Z",
        "description": "test 6",
        "accountHolder": "Bob",
        "accountType": "SAVINGS"
    },

The below Express state machine was working off data from s3. There were 15k records (above example) being processed. The Prepare Data state just passes the data, it doesn't performance any kind of IO or computation
"Prepare Data": {
            "Type": "Pass",
            "Parameters": {
              "pk.$": "States.Format('Payment#{}', $.uuid)",
              "sk": "PAYMENT",
              "amount.$": "States.Format('{}', $.amount)",
              "bank.$": "$.bank",
              "accountNumber.$": "$.accountNumber",
              "accountHolder.$": "$.accountHolder",
              "accountType.$": "$.accountType",
              "branchCode.$": "$.branchCode",
              "type.$": "$.type",
              "date.$": "$.date",
              "description.$": "$.description",
              "status": "CREATED"
            },
            "ResultPath": "$.preparedItem",
            "Next": "Finish"
          }

The Maximum Concurrency for this execution was set to 10000.
Is this the kind of performance we should expect from Step Functions, or is there something I'm missing? I expected this configuration to process everything in less than a minute.

RESULTS



Our Step Functions use services like SQS, DynamoDB and Lambda, and we thought these might be degrading a bit of performance. But after stripping things bare, it seems the issue might be the step functions themselves.

A few questions to clarify. From what I see here, you have data in S3 with 15,000 records and you are using Distributed Map to have Step Functions read that data, extract 15,000 items, process each of them in separate Express Item Processor (child execution) that simply uses a single pass state to manipulate the input, then write the results back to S3. And this is taking approximately 3 minutes. I will assume this is correct, but please clarify if not. More in a subsequent comment.

When you have large volumes of small data records to process, you will absolutely want to batch the items. This reduced overhead by ensuring you have fewer executions.

Have you tried any of the optimisation steps advised here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-best-practices.html?

@JustinCallison Yes, your assessment is correct... I'm gonna try batches and see if there is any improvement. I assume, increasing the concurrency limit is double-edged sword since it results in more executions, therefor more overhead?

@JustinCallison Batching has significantly improved the performance. The above executed in ~10 seconds after 100 batch per execution. Thank you

Great, I'm glad that worked. I added an answer to make this more accessible for others later. Regarding your question of whether increased concurrency would help, the answer is not much. We don't allow more than 10k concurrency but it's the incremental latency of each discrete step that adds up anyway. If your total number of batches is less than the max concurrency, that will allow Step Functions to spin them all up at the same time. And when that's not possible, there is some additional latency involved in ensuring all complete before starting more. But the effect is far smaller.

When processing large numbers of small items with Step Functions Distributed Map, you will want to employ batching. Batching reduces the cumulative overhead of managing discrete units of work when that isn't necessary or helpful.
Batching is a built in capability with Distributed Map. You configure it using the ItemBatcher property. You can control the maximum batch size by the number of items per match or the size per batch.

Once employ batching, you will need to handle the array of items in your ItemProcessor, which you can either do sequentially or in parallel (using the Inline Map state in your Express ItemProcessor).
If you want to learn more about Distributed Map and how to use it at scale, here are a couple of re:Invent sessions from 2022 and 2023 that you might find useful.
